# Can you set up a scanner with a different model

Tags: scanner

I just bought an officjet Pro 7740. It is new enough it is not in the printer/scanner data base, but I can install the printer side by using the OfficeJet Pro 7612 wide format driver in CUPS. Is it possible to install a scanner with a similar model as well or do I need to just scan from windows for now.
                  Thanks

Comment: That's a nice printer. I would go to HP support website and ask them: [http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Software-and-Drivers/bd-p/Software]

Comment: Similar models are listed on the HPLIP support page: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_pro_l7700.html